# Asp.net React+Redux, tracking a user who has logged in?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, react-redux

I've set up an Asp.Net Identity system for my WebAPI using this tutorial: http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/b957238b-e2dd-4401-bfd7-f0b8d984786d.aspx, everything works great and the only difference is I'm using React+Redux for my frontend which sends action calls to the WebAPI which takes care of user registrations and logging in.

When registering users are created successfully and added to a database, when logging in signInManager.SignIn() returns success so everything is great.

However subsequent calls to other WebAPI actions does not show the user to be authenticated. I'm not sure why this is and can only assume it has to do either with the fact I'm using a WebAPI seperately or my frontend is different.

I've tried using Cookie authentication following this example but it hasn't helped: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Another thing I tried was to use a ProxyController on the front end. So React+Redux runs fetch's on the proxy controller actions which will then in turn make the call to the WebAPI. I thought this might work if I use the same HttpClient for all my action calls to the WebAPI (perhaps it preserves some form of state?).

Code below is what I tried:

```
    HttpClient httpClient;

    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Login(string username, string password)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage;
        {
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, 
                "http://localhost:62356/api/mywebapi/login?username=" + username + "&password=" + password);
            responseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        }
        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        return new JsonResult(json);
    }

// api/mywebapi/test tries to confirm through signInManager is user is signed in 
//using: (!signInManager.IsSignedIn(HttpContext.User)) which returns false, // if I 
add an [Authenticate] decorator to the 'Test' action function the below code 
returns a 404...
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public async Task<JsonResult> Test()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage;
        {
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,
                "http://localhost:62356/api/mywebapi/test");

            responseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        }

        dynamic result = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();

        return new JsonResult(result);
    }
```

Is there something I'm missing from the equation?

Comment: I don't think I understood your question correctly but in order to work with **React JS** and make calls to your API I would suggest to use **Token based** authentication (e.g. for ASP.NET there is a lib for UseJwtBearerAuthentication or something). And when user loges in API will return a *token* which you will save in `localStorage`. And in order to make authenticated requests you have to read token from your `localStorage` and pass it as a header something like this `"Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('token)'`

Comment: Ah ok I think what you say makes sense. My apologies I am still learning this. So with a token I can let my WebAPI know who the user is? Are there any tutorials I can look at for making that work with an asp.net core 2 WebAPI and React+Redux frontend? I did look at OAuth2 but the best example I could find wasn't compatible with Asp.Net Core 2...

Comment: Np. Well that is a problem actually. There aren't much tutorials about asp net core 2.0. I do have a project that uses exactly asp net core 2.0 with JWT token authentication and with React JS (redux) on the front side unfortunately can't share it with you. If I have time I will try to share some codes with you later today. Regarding your question about token. Yes your `[Authorize]` attribute will work like a charm :) if you will construct your token correctly of course (for role authentication you need to add new field `roles: "Admin"` to token as a claim).