# asp.net dual authentication having to sign in twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core-mvc

I've successfully followed this guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?tabs=aspnetcore2x) to allow authentication for both my react/redux front end (using js fetch to pass a jwt token to Web API), plus the server-rendered "back end" (plain MVC) admin pages.

I can log into either "side" of the application, but I'm forced to log in again to get to the other side.  The links to the server-side part of the app are plain "a href" tags, so can't pass the jwt header token.  Is there any way to make the sign in to one auth scheme (e.g. JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) reflect the fact you're signed in in the other scheme (e.g. CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)?

Note: similar to [Asp.net React+Redux, tracking a user who has logged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036516/asp-net-reactredux-tracking-a-user-who-has-logged-in)

This is my AuthController login method:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("~/api/auth/login")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string username, string password)
    {
        // Ensure the username and password is valid.
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
        if (user == null || !await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password))
        {
            return BadRequest(new
            {
                error = "", //OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                error_description = "The username or password is invalid."
            });
        }

        // Ensure the email is confirmed.
        if (!await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user))
        {
            return BadRequest(new
            {
                error = "email_not_confirmed",
                error_description = "You must have a confirmed email to log in."
            });
        }

        _logger.LogInformation($"User logged in (id: {user.Id})");

        var token = GetClientToken(user, _jwtOptions);

        // Do server-side login too (NB: This DOESNT WORK!)
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, true, false);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("Could not log in to server side");
        }

        return Ok(new { token });
    }
```

Comment: [token in the a href](https://joseoncode.com/2013/05/22/activation-links-with-hawk/). Not sure that conflating auth mechanisms is the best approach.

Comment: if you want to pass a token from one to the other why can't you just use one auth scheme? Is it only some users who can log into both parts? Even then some authorisation rules would surely take care of that.

Comment: I'm not averse to using one scheme (indeed it would be simpler) however the accepted best practice seems to be JWT for React<->Web API calls and I'm not sure how you'd use that in MVC-land

Comment: Well MVC can make calls to an API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I fixed this by redirecting to the Server side login form for both the client and server login.

The server side login ("/Account/Login") form authenticated the client (jwt) and server (cookie) auth schemes

The client side login ("~/api/auth/login") form only authenticated the client (jwt).